# Can I serve static files (css, html, etc.) from a different server in Django

Tags: python, django, apache

So I'm trying to serve templates, images, css and other static files from a Web Server (frontend) running Apache into an App Server (backend) running Django, the Django app is already proven to work locally so I splited static files and push them into the Web server and the .py files into the App Server, so far I've seen that I need to use *mod_wsgi* package from Apache and then run

> `$ python manage.py collectstatic`

So it makes a copy of those static files into the App Server. But the problem comes when changing the urls of every template.

Also I saw this other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025490/serve-static-html-in-django) but I'm not sure if I implement that solution I still need to do the *mod_wsgi* thing. Can someone please help me out here please? Or give me some advice on how to do it? Thanks